# if else with and operator in pyspark for comparing two dataframe columns

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to `compare two columns` of a dataframe but it results in error. PFB code:

```
if((df3.name==df3.KEY) and (df3.id==df3.seq_id)):
    print("hey")
else:
    print("hey1")
```

where `df3` is a dataframe. It throws below error:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I tried several solutions from SO blog and changing operator from `and` to `&` but it didn't help.

I tried converting to `pandas` and then perform action and it works well in shell but doesn't work on IDE:

```
df4 = df3.toPandas()
if(df4['name'].equals(df4['KEY']) & df4['id'].equals(2)):
    print("hey")
else:
    print("hey1")
```

Comment: Your approach will not work - what are you trying to do? The operation `df3.name==df3.KEY` returns a whole [`Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) of `BooleanType`. It does not make sense to try to evaluate that `Column` within an `if` block. Please try to provide a [mcve]. Could this be an [XY Problem](http://www.xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I want to compare two columns values, if it matches then perform some action

Comment: Can anyone help me over here ?